# How to add copy button to Discord Webhook embed message

Tags: discord, webhooks

[image]

In the image above, you can see the text with in blue color and the copy button.

I want to create the same thing, but don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I have found one thing. the `\`text`\` with background. 
`Text` in discord

Comment: I am not sure how to make copy button in discord chat. please help me

Answer (score 2):

I just checked by joining the discord you sent. And the copy icon is just a simple icon with no use.

You can't at the moment make a "copy to clipboard" action using any sort of text inside an embed. (It was already suggested a while ago [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360071963952-Copy-To-Clipboard-Within-Embeds))
Maybe Discord will add this feature someday.

If you just need to copy the exact same thing, they are doing something like:

```markdown
[click me](https://google.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord has not added this functionality yet. The icon there is likely just a small image.. However, you can use an external library called pyperclip. Then, run the following code with an interaction.(interactions are discord 2.0 stuff but are pretty stable in my opinion)
`import pyperclip pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')`

Comment: To clarify, run the pyperclip code when an interaction button is pressed. For mor info check the discord docs